# How to prove $\forall a,b,x \in \mathbb N \exists c,d \in \mathbb N\setminus${$a,b$}$: (x-a)(x-b) = (x-c) (x-d)$

Tags: quadratics

The statement $\forall a,b,x \in \mathbb N \exists c,d \in \mathbb N\setminus${$a, b$}$: (x-a)(x-b) = (x-c) (x-d)$ seems to be true for me. But I really have no idea how to prove it formally. Is there a way?

Comment: I'm confused. Did you mean to type $c,d\in \Bbb N\setminus\{a,b\}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Going to eddit it.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** true; Here is a trivial counter example: $a = b = 0$. We attempt to find non-zero $c,d$ such that $(x-c)(x-d) = x^2$. By applying the distributive property twice, we find

$$x^2 - (c+d)x + cd = x^2$$
$$-(c+d)x + cd = 0$$
$$(c+d)x = cd$$

Obviously, for all $x \in \Bbb R$, no non-zero $cd$ satisfy this.

Comment: Since $a,b \in \mathbb N$ they can't be 0.

Comment: @M.Dou This is a matter of definition- some countries (e.g. France) and fields of mathematics (e.g. Logic) include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$, others do not.

Comment: If c=d=2, x=1 works.

Answer (score 1):

The statement $(x-a)(x-b)=(x-c)(x-d)$ simplifies to $x^2-(a+b)x+ab=x^2-(c+d)x+cd$ so $a+b=c+d$ and $ab=cd$. But then consider $a=1,b=2$. $2$ has no other factorization in the natural numbers, so this is false.

Worth noting that this is also false in the integers, for a similar reason. The only other factorization of $2$ in the integers is $2=(-1)(-2)$. However, this does not satisfy $a+b=c+d$.